# How can I Host a Website on a Local Server with Port 80 Redirect and a Dynamic IP?

Tags: apache-httpd, dns, port-forwarding

I am on Three Mobile UK which only issue a dynamic IP and apparently blocked all http ports including 80 so I got a domain [stephenogidan.ddns.net](http://stephenogidan.ddns.net/) from No-IP to fix this issue. So far, I haven't been able to pull it off! This is what I have done so far:

1. Set up DDNS on my Huawei B535 Router which updates my IP with No-IP. As at the time of writing this, these are the details:

   ```
   My Public IP Address: 188.28.69.7
   No-IP Address: 188.28.69.7:8080 (With Port 80 Redirect)
   Dns Lookup IP Address: 34.199.8.144
   ```
2. Set up Virtual Server for port forwarding on the same router with the following details:

   ```
   Name: Ubuntu
   WAN Port: 80-80
   LAN IP Address: 192.168.8.133
   LAN Port: 80-80
   Protocol: TCP/UDP
   ```
3. Set up a host file pointing to a folder with test `index.html`. The site has been enabled.

   ```
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/stephenogidan.conf

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName stephenogidan.ddns.net
       DocumentRoot /var/www/stephenogidan
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. And finally, this is my `/etc/hosts` file:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   127.0.1.1 ubuntu_server
   127.0.0.1 stephenogidan.ddns.net
   ```

When I visit [stephenogidan.ddns.net](http://stephenogidan.ddns.net/), below is the response:

> This site can't be reached. www.stephenogidan.ddns.net's server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. http://xxxxogidan.ddns.net/ forwards to port 8080, but should forward to port 80, there is something wrong in your ddns setup (maybe this `No-IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`).
2. http://www.xxxxogidan.ddns.net/ is not the same as  http://xxxxogidan.ddns.net/, only the latter one will work (when (1) is fixed).
3. Your site is listed in `available-sites`, you have to enable it, e.g. using `a2ensite <site>`

Comment: First, I will try and see if I can change No-IP's port to 80 because my router won't let me forward to port 80. Second, I will adjust my host file to `www.stephenogidan.ddns.net`. However, the site is enabled already. I will update you after I make the adjustments.

Comment: your router forwards port 80 ...  no, www won't work from ddns site. leave out www

Comment: I have done the adjustments but charges nothing. However, the site is working if I make `/etc/hosts` entries on the server and on a client (eg laptop). Also if I type `192.168.8.133 ` on all devices on my network it shows the website. There is a detail I am missing and for the life of me I can't figure it out!